# Subsequent Apple Sign-ins (Firebase, iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I am using `Firebase` and [integrating Apple Sign-In in my iOS app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple#reauthentication_and_account_linking).

I have the initial sign-in working, but am admittedly confused as to how to manage subsequent logins via Apple after a user logs out as documentation outlines that `userInfo` is not disclosed for subsequent logins (for the same Apple ID).

I've seen sparse comments on storing to `UserDefaults` or parsing the `identityToken` received when signing in, but I couldn't find anything clearly definitive and instructional that encompasses a solve for the below scenarios that require `userInfo` to come into play:

1. Checking if user already exists with email and giving user immediate access to app as a result
2. Linking multiple auth providers (i.e. linking Google to existing Apple account)
3. User deleting app from device and reinstalling
4. User opting to hide email on *first* sign-in

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solve was to use the library JWTDecode and parse for the email from the `identityToken`. Hope this to work consistently.